# reduced latency and improved transaction speed since new data centre opens

Tags: data, performance, trust

I wonder if there is a direct reduction in transaction time for EU based customers as a result of the new data centre that opened in the UK last week (w/c 27th Oct '14), we have noticed a reduction in the refresh time taken for dashboards and also in general the page refreshed have less delays.